# Lingering MAMP Files

Tags: macos, mac, uninstall, mamp

I installed MAMP a while ago and didn't enjoy it very much, so I uninstalled it (moved from Applications to Trash). Today I discovered that there are still MAMP files on my machine, but I can't seem to do anything about them.

Here's what's happening. If I do `locate MAMP` in Terminal, I get a long list of files like this:

- /Applications/MAMP
- /Applications/MAMP/Icon
- /Applications/MAMP/LEAME.rtf
- /Applications/MAMP/LIESMICH.rtf
- /Applications/MAMP/LISEZ-MOI.rtf
- /Applications/MAMP/Library

So, naturally, I go to my Applications folder to remove the files, but MAMP is nowhere to be found.

Furthermore, terminal-ing to the Applications folder (`cd ~/../../Applications`) and trying to delete it (`rm MAMP`) leads to a 'no such file' message.

What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locate is not a real time search. It runs periodically to update a database of all file locations. What's probably happening is your locate database is outdated.

Comment: That appears to be what was going on. I ran an update on the DB and it no longer found any files. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  If you want to do a live search, use 'find'.  You can use Spotlight's index from CLI by doing 'mdfind'.

Answer (score -1):

Applications create helper files to assist in running the application and storing data.You might also want to check `~/Library` and `/Library` for other files.

When I delete applications I use [AppZapper](http://www.appzapper.com/). It searches for other files and gives you the option to remove those as well as the core application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid it's not extremely helpful. Terminal is specifically stating that the files are in `/Applications`, but as a precaution I checked the folders you suggested and didn't find anything. I also already know about AppZapper and similar software, but thanks for the link regardless.

Comment: Could be that the `locate` database hasn't been updated. Like a Spotlight index or a Google cache.

Comment: You can also do a Spotlight search (including system files) for the application/company name and delete the relevant files manually.